# Error con Ajax: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length'

Tags: javascript, jquery

La pregunta posiblemente este repetida, pero mis condiciones son un poco extrañas

La funcion de jquery no quiere mandar los datos en el "else" de una funcion pero si lo hace en el "if", no tengo idea de porque no lo hace.

Este es el comienzo:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){ //Esconder todo el body del index al iniciar sesion con efecto FadeOut
        EnergyPointBS();
        $("#Entrar").click(function(){
            $("#contenido").fadeOut();
     });
      var today = new Date();
      var diass = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate(); //Resta la fecha por un dia para obtener el dia anterior
      Historial(diass); //Se debe comunicar con una funcion hace al historial funcionar
    });
```

Aquí empieza el problema. La funcion de $.ajax({ no se comunica con la función en el "else", y como no logra hacer que el "else" funcione la función no corre, el "if" si funciona ya que no tira ningún error allí. No da ningún error de PHP si preguntan, solo da ese error que describí en el titulo

```
    function Historial(data){ //Es el historial en si
        var fechaRetos;
        var f = new Date();
        var getdate = f.getDate();
        if(getdate >= 1 || getdate <= 9){
            getdates = '0'+getdate;
            var fechaHoy = f.getFullYear()+"-"+(f.getMonth() +1)+"-"+getdates;
            if(data >= fechaHoy){
            $("#errorHistorial").fadeIn();
            $("#historialMente").empty();   
            $("#historialCuerpo").empty();   
            $("#historialEnergia").empty();   
            $("#2020-02-28").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-01-04").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-10-26").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-10-27").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-10-28").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-10-29").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-10-30").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-10-31").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");

            $("#2016-11-01").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-02").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-03").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-04").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-05").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-06").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-07").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-08").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-09").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");    
            $("#2016-11-10").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-11").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-12").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-13").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-14").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-15").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-16").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-17").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-18").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");    
            $("#2016-11-19").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-20").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-21").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-22").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-23").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-24").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-25").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-26").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-27").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-28").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-29").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-30").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");

            $("#2016-12-01").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo"); 
            $("#2016-12-02").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo"); 
            $("#2016-12-03").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");                                
            $("#2016-12-04").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo"); 

            $("#2016-10-21").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo"); 
            $("#2016-10-22").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");                                
            $("#2016-10-23").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");    

            fechaRetos = data;
            $("#"+fechaRetos).addClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");          
            return false;
        }else{
            $("#errorHistorial").fadeOut();
            $("#2020-02-28").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-01-04").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-10-24").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-10-25").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-10-26").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-10-27").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-10-28").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-10-29").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-10-30").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-10-31").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");

            $("#2016-11-01").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-02").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-03").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-04").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-05").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-06").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-07").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-08").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-09").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");    
            $("#2016-11-10").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-11").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-12").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-13").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-14").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-15").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-16").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-17").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-18").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");    
            $("#2016-11-19").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-20").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-21").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-22").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-23").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-24").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-25").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-26").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-27").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-28").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-29").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");
            $("#2016-11-30").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");

            $("#2016-12-01").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo"); 
            $("#2016-12-02").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo"); 
            $("#2016-12-03").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");                                
            $("#2016-12-04").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo"); 

            $("#2016-10-21").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo"); 
            $("#2016-10-22").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");                                
            $("#2016-10-23").removeClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");        

            data = fechaRetos;
            $("#"+fechaRetos).addClass("btnDiaRedondoactivo");

            //Reto Mente
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"function/puntosDAO.function2.php",
                dataType:"JSON",
                data:"&tipo=historialMente&hm_date="+fechaRetos+"&registro_id="+registro_id,
                success: function(data){
                    if(data.state == "ok"){     
                        $("#historialMente").empty();                                       
                        $.each(data.result, function(i, item){
                        var intencion = item.intencion_note;
                        var resintencion = intencion.slice(0,20);
                        var datHistorial = '<div class="retosTareas completo" style="padding-bottom:15px;"><h2><?php echo $labeldash[11]; ?></h2><div style="min-height: 150px;"><h4 style="">'+item.mente_label+'</h4></div><div style="min-height: 100px;"><span>'+item.mente_reto+'</span><br><br></div><div class=""><img src="images/hand.svg"></div><div style="text-transform: uppercase;font-weight: lighter;font-size: 26px; margin-top: 28px;"><?php echo $final[4]; ?> <span title="'+item.intencion_note+'">'+resintencion+'...</span><br><p style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; margin-top: 10px;"><?php echo $final[1]; ?> '+item.mente_puntos+' <?php echo $final[2]; ?></p></div></div>';     

                        $("#historialMente").append(datHistorial);

                        });
                    }else{
                        $.ajax({
                            type:"POST",
                            url:"function/puntosDAO.function2.php",
                            dataType:"JSON",
                            data:"&tipo=comprobarRetoMente&mente_date="+fechaRetos,
                            success: function(data){
                            $("#historialMente").empty();                                       
                                $.each(data.result, function(i, item){

                                var datHistorial = '<div class="retosTareas nocompleto" style="padding-bottom:55px;"><h2><?php echo $labeldash[11]; ?></h2><div style="min-height: 150px;"><h4 style="">'+item.mente_label+'</h4></div><div style="min-height: 100px;"><span>'+item.mente_reto+'</span><br><br></div><div class=""><img src="images/hand_no.svg"></div><div style="text-transform: uppercase;font-weight: lighter;font-size: 26px; margin-top: 28px;"><?php echo $final[3]; ?><br></div></div>';     

                                $("#historialMente").append(datHistorial);

                                });
                            }
                        });                 
                    }               
                }
            });
```

Aqui es donde se tiene que comunicar:

```
case "historialMente": 
    $p = new puntosDAO2();     
    $resultados = $p->historialMente($_POST['hm_date'], $_POST['registro_id']); 
    if(sizeof($resultados)>0){
        $r["state"] = "ok";
        $r["result"] = $resultados;
    }else{
        $r["state"] = "error";
        $r["result"] = "No pasa nada";                  
    }  
break;
```

Y esta es la clase a la cual se tiene que comunicar esa función anterior, pero no logra pasar de la funcion anterior

```
public function historialMente($hm_date, $registro_id){
    $con = DBManager::con();
    $q = "SELECT * FROM reto_historial_mente INNER JOIN reto_mente 
    ON reto_historial_mente.mente_id = reto_mente.mente_id INNER JOIN reto_intencion 
    ON reto_historial_mente.hm_date = reto_intencion.intencion_date 
    WHERE reto_historial_mente.registro_id = '".$registro_id."' 
    AND reto_historial_mente.hm_date = '".$hm_date."' 
    AND reto_intencion.intencion_date = '".$hm_date."' 
    AND reto_intencion.registro_id = '".$registro_id."' 
    ORDER BY reto_historial_mente.mente_id DESC LIMIT 0,1";
    $rpta = mysqli_query($con, $q);
    mysqli_close($con);
    while($file = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rpta)){
        $this->r[]= $file;
    }
    return $this->r;
}
```

Comment: Este if es el que funciona? `if(getdate >= 1 || getdate <= 9){`

Comment: Ese funciona, tambien funciona el "if(data.state == "ok"){ ", pero su else no funciona

Comment: Imprime la variable $resultados antes de esta línea if(sizeof($resultados)>0){. Te devuelve siempre >0 por eso no entra en el else.

Comment: No imprime nada, mi problema esta en el else de "if(data.state == "ok"){", parece que no se puede comunicar con la function de "case "historialMente": "

Comment: Esto es correcto puntosDAO. en la url? No debería ser puntosDAO/functions2.php?

Comment: Si es correcto, las demas funciones funcionan

Comment: Con este `if(getdate >= 1 || getdate <= 9)` quieres limitar números entre 1 y 9? entonces deberías cambiar el operador `||` por `&&` porque cero es menor o igual a 9 y cumple la condición, 10 es mayor o igual a uno y también la cumple.

Comment: Hice lo que me pidio Trilby y ahora me da un error de "Array to string conversion" que era por imprimir la variable resultados, pero el error descrito sigue alli

Comment: cual debería ser el resultado de f.getDate(), ¿que tipo de dato devuelve?

Comment: cambia el `data:"&tipo=comprobarRetoMente&mente_date="+fechaRetos,` por `data: { tipo:"comprobarRetoMente",mente_date:fechaRetos },`

Answer (score 2):

Según un [problema similar](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2579) al que mencionás en tu título, en el método `$.each` estás pasando como parámetro un valor `undefined` o `null`.

Antes de recorrer `data.result`, primero comprobá que contenga algún valor. También verificá qué versión de JQuery estás utilizando.

Comment: Logre hacer console log a la variable "data" antes de data.result y me tira un undefined. Estoy usando jquery-3.4.1

Comment: Así como sugiere @Bryro, entonces intentá enviando como data { tipo:"comprobarRetoMente",mente_date:fechaRetos } en lugar de lo que tenés actualmente. Y si no devuelve resultados, entonces deberías incluir en el success lo siguiente: if(data.result!==undefined){...}

Comment: Revise usando console.log y me di cuenta que el ajax no corre, hice el cambio que me pidieron igualmente